# What is wrong here? Why is it showing type error when it shouldn't be?

Tags: python-3.x

```
class student :
    def __init__(self,name,age,grade):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.grade = grade   # 0 - 100

    def get_grade(self):
        return self.grade

class Course :
    def __init__(self, name, max_students):
        self.name = name
        self.max_students = max_students
        self.students = []

    def add_student(self, student):
        if len(self.students) < self.max_students :
            self.students.append(student)
            return True
        return False
    def get_average_grade(self):
        value = 0
        for i in self.students :
            value += student.get_grade() # this part had the error

        return value / len(self.students)

s1 = student('Bob', 12, 50)
s2 = student('Joe', 12, 60)
s3 = student('Sadie', 12, 100)

Course1 = Course('Chemistry', 5)
Course1.add_student(s1)
Course1.add_student(s2)
Course1.add_student(s3)
print(Course1.students[0].name)
print(Course1.get_average_grade())
```

Comment: I wanted to print out the average by print(Course1.get_average_grade()) but it didn't work

Comment: Add the error traceback. It contains (far) more useful information than "type error".

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in self.students :
    value += student.get_grade() # this part had the error
```

It has an error because you're using the class name `student` instead of the subject of the loop, `i`.

You'd be more successful if you instead used `value += i.get_grade()`, though I'd probably choose a better variable name as well.

Or you could replace the entire body of `get_average_grade()` with the more Pythonic:

```
return sum([item.get_grade() for item in self.students]) / len(self.students)
```

> As an aside, you *may* also want to consider what will happen when there are *no* students in the list.

Comment: Thank you it works now! Sorry for the bad post I'm still a beginner :)

Comment: That's okay, @KSP, all levels of experience are welcome here. In case you're curious, you can just enter your code as is, mark it with mouse or shift-arrows, and use CTRL-K to indent it four spaces (which makes it a code block).